# Eagle: How do I edit the dimension layer?

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

While creating a via, a drill shape somehow ended up on my dimension layer. Even though I've deleted the via the drill hole remains and produces an error. How can I edit the dimension layer and delete the drill hole?

Screenshot attached. Only the dimension layer (layer 20) is shown.

[image: Eagle screenshot]

Comment: Try to show all layers and then select top/bottom layer and place drill shape.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out this was an artifact left by the design rule check. Clearing the errors cleared the drill shape.

Comment: You can also use View | Redraw to refresh the current view. That often gets rid of any artifacts.

Comment: I'm glad you came back to address your own question. I was wondering how to recreate the problem so I could try and provide an answer.